# What does "i360: Error in global initialization" mean in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, webserver

A PHP software I wrote has been working fine for years suddenly throws this error: **i360: Error in global initialization**

This error is being thrown from the callback function `register_shutdown_function('my_shutdown');`

The callback function is just something this:

```
function my_shutdown ()
{
    chdir(getcwd());

    $e = error_get_last();
    if ($e)
        trigger_error($e['message'].' on '.$e['file'].' ('.$e['line'].')', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

The full error message that `trigger_error` throws is:

`i360: Error in global initialization 1 on Unknown (0)`.

It doesn't give much clue. Any ideas what could be causing it?

**Update 1:**
If I comment out the entire `my_shutdown()` function, the script works fine but I am still intrigue as to why this error happened just today after years of working fine.

**Update 2:**
Tentative info: this appears to be related to Imunify360, a security software for web servers (which my host uses that I'm not aware of or have control over). Investigation ongoing.

Comment: That doesn't look like a PHP error. Maybe it's related to https://www.i-360.com/

Comment: @Barmar That's weird, that site is has no relation to the script in any way.

Comment: That message is coming from something that happened before `my_shutdown()` was called. This function just prints information about the last error that happened before shutting down.

Comment: So commenting out this function doesn't prevent the error, it just keeps it from printing the message describing it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I am still investigating the cause of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was confirmed to be coming from Imunify360 (a security software for web servers). At the time of this writing, the issue was already fixed on their end. I presume an update was applied to servers using it so if you're still getting this error, contact your host.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by Imunify360 because of a recent update to include a feature called "Proactive Defense":

https://www.imunify360.com/blog/meet-imunify360-with-proactive-defense-the-sophisticated-protection-against-any-kind-of-malware-all-in-one-nice-package

To fix this you need to have your host disable the extension over all PHP versions:

```
sed -i "s/extension=i360.so/;extension=i360.so/g" /opt/alt/php*/etc/php.ini
```

That should fix the problem for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened just today. It disappears when I delete my cron jobs on Hawk Host cpanel.

Comment: Yes! the software is hosted from Hawkhost too. I think we're on to something here.